# Parse fetches objects without any actual data

Tags: javascript, parse-server, parse-javascript-sdk

My Parse SDK seems to be doing weird things, check this out:

```
await Parse.User.logIn("testuser", "123asd");

this.initMap().then( correct => this.correctInit = correct);
    const places = await PlaceDAO.getAllForPosition(this.coords);
    this.placesList = places;
    console.log(this.placesList)
```

I login, and then I fetch all the places from this DAO method:

```
export class PlaceDAO {

    static async getAllForPosition(geopoint) {

        try {
            let query = new Parse.Query("Place");
            query.withinKilometers("location", {latitude: geopoint.lat, longitude: geopoint.lng}, 20);
            return await query.find();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("DAO ERROR: ", err)
        }
    }


}
```

When I read what I receive, both after the query.find() or in the controller, what I see is these two objects; they have the proper ID, but none of the properties defined in the Parse class. ACL is configured for all public read-write in this class... Check it out:

[image]

Strangely, if I check the "network"...:

[image]

Yeah, it seems that my app actually receives the whole objects! Though this list is not accessible from the Parse SDK... it just cuts it down... why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access properties of a `Parse.Object` you need to use the `.get(key)` method. (see: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#objects)

For example:

```
const places = await ParseDAO.getAllForPosition(position)
places.forEach((place) => {
    console.log(place.get('placeName'))
});
```

This should log all the place names

Comment: Could you elaborate on this example? I'm unclear on how this is implemented on the server and the docs have not made it any clearer for me. Does this have to be done for each key you want Parse to show? Thanks.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. You have to read each key by calling ‘place.get(key)’ where key is the name of the property you want to read in your object

Comment: Thanks for the details. I understand now.